# Permission Denied - External Program Call Using Shoes With Ruby

Tags: ruby, shoes, backticks

Here is my code, I'm trying to simply open Adobe Acrobat Reader.  When I use this code, or `/Applications/Adobe Reader.app`, the console tells me that "permission denied".  Any ideas on how to get around this?

```
Shoes.app :width => 200, :height => 200 do
  flow :width => 800, :margin => 10 do
    button "OK" do
      `/Users/Travis/Desktop/test.fdf`
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: you typed .fdf , it shouldn't be .pdf ??

Comment: No, I have another file writing to a .fdf file, in order to fill in the forms of a .pdf file.  When the .fdf file is opened, the .pdf file is what the user will see and be able to print or manipulate from there.  I can write to the .fdf file, I just can't open it.  Also, I've tried other files (like Travis.jpg) and I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding more permissions to the file. You can do this via the termial:

```
chmod -R 777 /directory/file
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'm getting past the permission denied, but now it's giving me an "Exec format error".  I'm now digging to find the answer to that problem.  I appreciate the help!